# android: How to pick contacts phone num

Tags: android, contacts

I need to pick contact phone num, and I used to do it like this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CONTACT_FROM_RESULT);
```

But, when a contact has multiple numbers, the pick activity only list one contact, and can only select one phone.

What can I do to display contacts' every phone num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask contact picker to show one contact per phone, so contact with multiple phones will appear several times:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted! How do I know what contact they selected though, I want to share it in a shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Map<String, String> lookupPhoneNoAndContactId(){
    Map<String, String> phonenumbers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            phonenumbers
                    .put(cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
        }
        return phonenumbers;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```